# Can we use product configurator In Custom Module Odoo

Tags: odoo

I create a custom module in my Odoo, one of my models is having a relation to product variant or Product.Product model, I want to use product configurator like in the sales_product_line tree. I already trying to use the widget on my field and import the product configurator module And try to make my view code the same as sales_product_line code, I even add the product_configurator javascript but still no luck. Is there any workaround to achieve this.
This is the view that I trying to achieve
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per My knowledge Product Configurator can not use in the custom model, This module is only the foundation for external configuration interfaces such as 'product_configurator_wizard' or 'website_product_configurator'.

> **This module does not configure custom products**

but offers the basis for generating, validating, updating configurable products using configuration interfaces.

Thanks!

Karmdip Joshi

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, sorry its been a long time. I still don't get your answer so I can use product_configurator_wizard in my custom module? Is it like a widget or something

Comment: I think you can't. But not sure about this.